# how to populate dropdown menu item from databaes

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i have 2 dropdown menu and i want populate my 2nd dropdown menu items with my 1st dropdown menu item related. I mean my 1st dropdown menu items are **Apple, Samsung, HTC, Nokia**  etc. When i select Apple dropdown menu items populated by *iPhone 6s, iPhone 5s, iPhone 4s* etc. I can't explain it very well in english. Sorry my bad english.  I populated my 1st dropdown menu from database

```
function selectFactor(){
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * from Factors");
    while($record = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.$record['FactorID'].'">'.$record['FactorName'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

and display result in html file

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="bla()">
<?php selectFactor(); ?>
</select>
```

and i just try something with it bla bla bla...

```
function bla(){
    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var elementValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(elementValue);
}
```

how can i populate 2nd dropdown menu when 1st index is changed?
UPDATED!

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['selectedItem'];
function selectSum(){
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * from factor INNER JOIN sumd ON factor.factorID=model.factorID where factorNer='$name'");
    while($record = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.$record['factorID'].'">'.$record['modelNer'].'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query your database for the selected item:
get_data.php is the file you have to create where you will query your database.

You ont need this:

```
onchange="bla()
```

Just an ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#dropdown').change(function(){
       var selectedItem = $(this).val()  //your item id

        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data.php',
            data : selectedItem,
            dataType: "json",
            type : 'POST',
        })
        .done(function(data) {
             //put the returned data in the second selectbox
            var output = '';
            $.each(data, function(i, el){
                output += '<option value="'+el.name+'">'+el.name+'</option>'
           //where 'name' is at moment the placeholder of your returned data   
            })
            $('#dropdown2').html(output)
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
   })
})
```

If you are ready with your query and don't know how to put the returned data into the second selectbox, I will also help you with it.

NOTE: this is your second select that has to be populated you need an unique ID in it:

```
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
    //here will be the output of the available options
</select>
```

**One Important notice:**

I advise you (when you have this working) to switch to mysqli and not use mysql anymore. This is a SECURITY ISSUE and you are potentially vulnerable for mysql injection!!

Comment: Thanks you sir. I just write my php code with query. And now how to return data to my 2nd selectbox?

Comment: @NeoTeo You mean in the second selectbox. The first one you already have, which will be populated from your php. To do this I will need you to post your HTML page where the fist selectbox also is. I suppose also that you have checked if in the 'data' returned from the ajax call do you have the correct values.

Comment: Yes i mean 2nd selectbox. Here is my html.
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<?php selectFactor(); ?>
</select>
<select name="dropdown2">

</select>

Comment: Ok easy to do. Because I can not see how you return your data from the php,  just tell me which is your return response (e.g data), so I can update the answer.

Comment: <?php
$name = $_POST['selectedItem'];
function selectSum(){
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * from factor INNER JOIN sumd ON factor.factorID=model.factorID where factorNer='$name'");
 while($record = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<option value="'.$record['factorID'].'">'.$record['modelNer'].'</option>';
 }
}
?>
here is my php code. I think it's return select box to html.

Comment: Also if this answer was useful  for you, can be also for other users so please don't forget to up vote it.

Comment: That seems not to be correct. You need to echo json_encode($result); Please add this code to your question so I can read it and see if you passed your response correctly!

Comment: That is not correct. What you need in your select box are just the product names. So you need to fetch only those from your db. Than you will echo json_encode($result). You dont need to try to echo your options there. This will be done in the ajax call when we get the resonse (the product names) from DB. So you don't need there any function. Just pass your posted var $name = $_POST['selectedItem'];, than query DB $result = @mysql_query(fecth the names here) and than echo json_encode($result)

Comment: The $result array must contain just ONLY the names ( iPhone 6s, iPhone 5s, iPhone 4s)

Comment: when i print return data it's said 'null'.
.done(function(data) {
             //put the returned data in the second selectbox
    console.log(data);
        })

Comment: Did you correct your query a I sad?  If you  did update it in your answer please

Comment: Thank you. I will keep trying fix this problem.

Comment: @NeoTeo this is not difficult to do, if you manage to make your query to work properly an pass the right data to the ajax call you are done. I will updated so you can go on when you have managed this.